# Sklearn linear regression loss function not matching with manual code

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have been trying to replicate the result of cost as per Sklearn linear regression library with the manual code. There is a huge difference between the two and i am not able to figure out why. Here is the code from Sklearn:

SkLearn implementation:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.30)
classifier = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train,Y_train)
cost = np.sqrt(np.sum((np.dot(X_train,classifier.coef_.reshape(9,1)) + classifier.intercept_ - Y_train.reshape(478,1))**2))
print(cost)

cost = 4.236441942240197
```

My attempt of replicating the result:

```
a = X_train_rev.shape
assert(X_train_rev.shape == (478,10)) # assert shape of the X_train_rev
Y_train = Y_train.reshape(478,1)

alpha = 0.0005 # Learning_Rate
coefficient = np.random.randn(1,10) # Initialisation of coefficients including intercept

# Loop through iterations
for i in range(100000):
    cost = np.sqrt(np.sum((np.dot(X_train_rev,coefficient.T) - Y_train)**2)) # cost result
    if i % 10000 == 0: print(cost)
    grad = np.dot((np.dot(X_train_rev,coefficient.T) - Y_train).T, X_train_rev) # Compute Gradients
    coefficient = coefficient - (alpha * grad) # adjust coefficients including intercept



Cost after Iterations:
45.23042864973579
10.428401916963285
10.428401916963285
10.428401916963285
10.428401916963285
10.428401916963285
10.428401916963285
10.428401916963285
10.428401916963285
10.428401916963285
```

The cost, as per my manual code, is not further reducing and is much farther from the cost as per Sklearn. I tried playing with alpha variable but any increase in alpha results into cost tending towards positive infinity.

Please note that the X_train_rev data, used in my manual code, has 10 columns/features instead of 9 features in Sklearn training set because i added a column of 'ones' in the training set to represent intercept. Similarly, the coefficient vector too includes intercept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to replicate your problem

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

X, Y = make_regression(n_samples=500, n_features=9, bias=0, random_state=1)

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.30, random_state=1)
classifier = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
classifier.fit(X_train,Y_train)
cost = np.sqrt(np.sum((np.dot(X_train,classifier.coef_.reshape(9,1)) + classifier.intercept_ - Y_train.reshape(-1,1))**2))

print(cost)
print('Manual regression')
Y_train = Y_train.reshape(-1,1)

alpha = 0.0005 # Learning_Rate
coefficient = np.random.randn(1,9) # Initialisation of coefficients including intercept

# Loop through iterations
for i in range(100000):
    cost = np.sqrt(np.sum((np.dot(X_train,coefficient.T) - Y_train)**2)) # cost result
    if i % 10000 == 0: print(cost)
    grad = np.dot((np.dot(X_train,coefficient.T) - Y_train).T, X_train) # Compute Gradients
    coefficient = coefficient - (alpha * grad) # adjust coefficients including intercept
```

small adjustments to make the code fully reproducible. And I faced no problems. There is a small difference in MSE, but both scores are less then 1e-11, so it is a numerical issue.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Anvar. Your code helped me figure out the mistake i was making in the first place. I was running my manual code on another randomized set of training data. Stupid of me !! :)